# Spring cacheable force refresh

Tags: spring, spring-cache

In example, I have a webapp that shows recommended movies to each user. Service's method does an API call to another platform and returns movies. I have to implement following logic:
User requests his movies recommendations. If the API call was successfull, put it in the cache and return. Otherwise not (if the method returned null). But user also may press refresh button. In this case, evict cache for that user, do API call and put it in cache again. How can I force refresh the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `condition` parameter of `@Cacheable`.
If the evaluated value is `false`, the method will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `@CacheEvict` annotation that you can use on the method that triggers a "refresh". Check [the documentation for more details](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-evict)

Comment: Is it a way not to create another method with `@CacheEvict` annotation? Just like passing `boolean force` to method`s args and evict it if it's true?